# Is there a monotonically increasing sequence that is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I just read the following theorem:

### If a sequence of real numbers is increasing and bounded above, then its supremum is the limit.

How is it possible to have an increasing but bounded above sequence? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: $\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$

Comment: This: $\tan^{-1} n$

Comment: I think it is important to note that 'monatonically increasing sequence' **doesn't** mean that each term in the series expansion is bigger than the previous term! Monatonically increasing sequence **doesn't** mean $a_{n+1} > a_{n} $.

It only means that each new term adds some positive additional piece to the sum.  Monatonically increasing sequence **does** mean $a_n+a_{n+1} \geq a_{n}$

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero Although it *is* good form to say so, I suspect that in this case "increasing" does mean "strictly increasing."

Comment: @Noah Schweber I was editing my first comment for clarity when you commented; I think now it covers what you've mentioned.

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero That is wrong - what you've written is equivalent to "$a_{n+1}\ge 0$," which is not relevant.

Comment: @Noah Schweber, isn't $a_{n+1} \geq 0$ necessary for the series to be monotonically increasing (any $a_{n+k}<0$ would create a decrease), while $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1} = 0$ must also be true for the series summation as a whole to bounded?

Comment: I think you're confusing *sequence* and *series*, here. For instance, if we let $a_n=-{1\over n}$, this is an increasing sequence, all of whose terms are negative . . .

Comment: Yes, looks like I was indeed mixing up sequence and series.  Now what is proper etiquette here; do I leave my comments for others to read and not make the same mistake, or delete my comments to lessen the noise and cover my tracks?

Answer (score 4):

$\{ a_n \}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is one such sequence. You can easily verify that it's monotone increasing and it is bounded above by $1$. It converges at $1$, which is indeed its supremum.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - and in fact you've seen lots of them!

For example:

3.

3.1.

3.14.

3.141.

.
.
.

This sequence is implicit anytime you talk about the decimal expansion of $\pi$.

---

In fact, given any increasing bounded sequence $S$, there is a unique real number $\alpha$ which is the **supremum** of $S$ (that is, $\alpha$ is greater than every element of $S$, and is the least such real number). This $\alpha$ is to $S$ exactly as $\pi$ is to the sequence above. And, in fact, considerations like these are how to rigorously define the real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest one is $$a_n=\frac n{1+n}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as a 'controlled' increase, ala $\tan^{-1}n$ which goes to $\pi /2$ in the long term. This is bounded increase, as opposed to unbounded increase like $a_n = n$.

I'm being informal with the terms to give you more intuition.